# Broken link on Careers: Featured Company section

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, hyperlinks

On the Careers page (careers.stackoverflow.com) there's a section "Featured Company" in the right column.

At the very bottom of this section, the text "*n* jobs available" links to careers.stackoverflow.com/CompanyName, which leads to nowhere. It should probably link to careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/employer/CompanyName.

The same link is also broken on other Careers subpages, e.g. when selecting a location (for example: careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/location/berlin) the "*n* jobs available" link in the "Featured Company" section leads to careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/location/CompanyName (resulting in a "location unknown" warning.) Similar problem on tag pages.

Answer (score 1):

We've been doing a bunch of work with URL structure over the past week or so and it looks like a couple of links were being generated in an incorrect way.

I've updated these cases and pushed out to production, link is now working!

Thanks for the report!