# Careers Featured Company "Skills we're looking for" links are incorrect

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Similar to [Broken link on Careers: Featured Company section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269011/broken-link-on-careers-featured-company-section), the "Skills we're looking for" links in the Featured Company ad are missing `/company/` from the URLs.

i.e. the tags in the following image result in a 404:

[image: Example of skills we're looking for section]

Also, a length restriction on the "skills" tag field uh…might not be a bad idea.

Comment: Lol, they seem to misuse the tags :D

Comment: I fixed the job in question, we're looking into how it bypassed the limits...

Comment: Also in the process of fixing the broken URLs you mention at the start of your post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pushed a build to production that fixes the URL issue. We're looking into how that extra long tag got into the system!

Thanks for the report!